# How do I print a specific section of a line from a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a quiz game that asks the user what the title of a song is, when it is displayed as just the first letters for each word in the title, as well as the artist alongside it. I have a text file of 50 songs, all with a number (01, 02, etc), the first letters of each word in the title (e.g. "Wonderwall" would be shown written as "W_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"), the actual full song names and the artist name, all seperated by a comma. When trying to display the question to the user, it comes up with the error

```
title = field[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I fix this issue?

I managed to make this program work fully before, however I edited it so the questions are in a while loop, and now it doesn't work.

**EDIT -**

I have fully filled out the text file with the actualTitle field, but its still returning the error, and I've also removed a few problems with my code, here's a sample of the text file below:

```
01,O_ _ T_ _ _ R_ _ _,Old Town Road,Lil Nas X

02,B_ _ G_ _,Bad Guy,Billie Eilish

03,H_ _ _ W_ _ _ M_,Here With Me,Marshmello

04,A_ _ S_ _ _,All Star,Smash Mouth

05,T_ _ _,Talk,Khalid

06,E_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _,Earfquake,Tyler The Creator

07,S_ _ _ _ _,Sucker,Jonas Brothers

08,S_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _,Sunflower,Post Malone

09,P_ _ _ _ _ _,Perfect,Ed Sheeran

10,F_ _ _ _ _ L_ _ _ M_,Friend Like Me,Will Smith
```

**I have also updated the code below:**

```
    # giving the score and lives variables
score = 0
lives = 2
# importing the songs for the questions
songs = open("songsAndArtists.txt","r")
# a while loop for if the answer is right
correctAns = True
while correctAns == True and lives != 0:
    # reading the specific lines and sections
    question = songs.readlines()
    for line in question:
        field = line.split(",")
        num = int(field[0])
        actualTitle = field[1]
        title = field[2]
        artist = field[3]
    print("Song no.",num,":")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("What is the full title of",actualTitle,"by",artist)
    guess = str(input())
    # give user 3 points for correct on first try
    if guess == (title):
        print("Correct! +3 points")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print()
        score = score + 3
        print("You have",score,"points")
        print()
        False
    # give user a second chance to guess
    elif guess != (title):
        print("Your guess is wrong, try again")
        print()
        print("What is the full title of",actualTitle,"by",artist)
        guess2 = str(input())
        lives = lives - 1
        True
        # give user 1 point for correct on second try
        if guess2 == (title):
            print("You are right on your second try, +1 point!")
            score = score + 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print()
            print("You have",score,"points")
            print()
            False
        # user didnt answer question correct, game over   
        elif guess2 != (title):
            lives = lives - 1
            # writing user points to score file
            with open("scores.txt", "a") as score_board:
                print("You got that question wrong too many times, game over!")
                print("Your total score is",score)
                score_board.write("%d\n" % score)
                score_board.write("\n")
            if score >= 60:
                print("You did well!")
                exit()
            elif score >= 20 and score < 60:
                print("Not too bad, but you could have done better.")
                exit()
            elif score < 20 and score >= 0:
                print("That's not a very good score :(")
                exit()

songs.close()
```

I expected the segment from each line in the text file called "actualTitle" to be outputted to the user, alongside the "artist" segment, but instead it came up with the error I mentioned before:

```
title = field[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have a feeling this has a simple solution to it, I'm just a bit lost, so any help would be appreciated.
Thank you to anyone who helps :)

**UPDATE (again)**
I have solved the issue with the IndexError, and it no longer displays it, however now the program only outputs the final line from the "songs" text file and does this repeatedly. Additionally, I have changed the name of the while loop most of this operates in, as well as added a file writing system to the "score" variable (don't worry, it works), but I'm still getting the problem with only the last line being outputted.

I have now included a dictionary section, which looks like:

```
question = songs.readlines()
    for line in question:
        field = line.split(",")
        num = int(field[0])
        title = field[1]
        actualTitle = field[2]
        artist = field[3]
        # using dictionary for each field
        dictNum = {
            num: field[0]
        }
        dictTitle = {
            title: field[1]
        }
        dictActual = {
            actualTitle: field[2]
        }
        dictArtist = {
            artist: field[3]
        }
```

However it doesn't work and I'm very confused
(Note: I've made it so all outputs for the questions are the dictionaries, like 'dictActual' and so on.

Comment: an IndexError means that your list isn't long enough. Without being able to reproducte the problem, it's impossible to tell why that is the case. Try printing the field list and check if it has the correct value

Comment: DSC, thank you for your comment, this may be because I haven't fully filled out the text file with the "actualTitle" field correctly yet, so if this is an issue then it's purely my fault, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the `songs.readline()`, it will read the next line only. So, when you were looping through that one line, it was iterating over the characters in the line and `.split(',')` on a character will always give a list of size 1 when it's not a `','` and size 2 when character is a `','`. So, most of the cases that list[1] will give an index out of bounds exception.

Fix:

replace

```
question = songs.readline()
```

with

```
question = songs.readlines()
```

PS:

After the end of your for loop, all the info is getting lost but the last row:

```
field = line.split(",")
num = int(field[0])
actualTitle = field[1]
title = field[2]
artist = field[3]
```

There you are just assigning variables, and on each iteration, they will get overridden! After the loop's execution, only the last row's data will be visible in the variables.

You should keep the row data in a dictionary so that it could be looked up by a key later (field[0] can be the key in your case).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have corrected that issue and tested it, however I now have a problem with the code only outputting the final song in the list of 50, which is "50,D_ _ _ S_ _ _ B_ _ _ _ _ _ _,Dont Stop Believin,Journey", and even if answered correctly it just loops and asked the same question again.

Comment: Please update the same thing in the question description and put your latest code above.

Comment: I've updated it with the new "working" code and explained the next issue

Comment: I've just seen your PS section, how exactly would I do that? I'm only an amateur coder and really only know the basics.

Comment: I have also added one suggestion to fix your problem, please use dictionary. You will get multiple example of it online.

Comment: I'm trying to use dictionary but I'm confused, I've added an extension to the problem showing it.